# Teradata dbtables sync - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, teradata

I'm planning to find a software solution (free/opensource) method to sync two teradata tables (two different teradata environments). My plan is to run the active db and in case of a failure my application can switch programmatically to passive db. (so passive db should have all the data from active db) and application can work without any data inconsistency.

what are the options for data syncing between Teradata tables in two different hosts? (there are commercial plugins for those from teradata) but I'm looking for a feasible solution for a small project. can't spend lot of money on this.

Comment: Replication is a quite complex topic. There's https://www.symmetricds.org/ which seems to support Teradata.

Comment: You can programmatically implement a standby if your DB tables records can allow a timestamp_added kind of column. Then, with a heartbeat of 5 minutes or so, transfer these latest records using the tdload utility for data tunneling or just plain bteq.

Comment: There are Tools by Teradata out-of-the-box called Unity, to keep systems in sync.
In addition you could use Backup-Restore to move data periodically from system a to system b.
Third: If you want to create it by your own, check Temporal to get a timestamp to each record.